# why a footer positioned absolute disappears

Tags: html, css

I am currently learning HTML & CSS  and wrapping my head around positioning i.e fixed, relative and absolute. I understand the concepts of each pretty well , at least I thought I did until my footer tag completely disappeared within itself when I set it's position to absolute. I know your asking what does disappeared within itself mean ? It means I had to adjust the left position value from 1024 to 850 just to be able to see the footer again. Which makes me  ask why the did the position value jump so high after setting the footer the absolute?Essentially that's the question I am asking. I hope I explained well enough. I tried to include a picture but Stackoverflow wouldn't let me since this my first post. Also i had three other 3 other divs on the page with the footer, div and header elements positions are set to relative.......code below.

```css
main, header, footer{
    display: block;
}

.page-container{
    width: 95%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #050111;
    position:relative;
    
}

header{

    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background-color: blue;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

h1{
    color: white;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin: auto;
}

main{

    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    background-color: rgb(24, 223, 223);
    text-align: center;

}

footer{
    widows: 100%;;
    height: 120px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: blueviolet;
    text-align: center;
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <title>Layout practice</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page-container">
        <header>
            <h1>This is the header of the page</h1>

        </header>

        <main>
            <h1>Main Content</h1>

        </main>

        <footer>
           <h1>Footer</h1>

        </footer>

    
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add your CSS to the snippet in the question.

Comment: css added to original post.

Comment: @Chasencode do you want the footer to be fixed or moved at bottom of the page?

Comment: widows instead of width for your footer CSS?

Comment: Neither ,I just wanted to see how it would react to being positioned abosolute. It was already at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @ JasonB.. Uhh yep that was the mistake . Noob error lol. Thanks !

Answer (score -1):

`position:absolute;` will place an element relative to its ancestor element. So if you positioned your footer as absolute it will start from where the body of the page starts.

```
footer{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Adding `bottom:0;` will place your element at the very bottom of the body.